# How to extract latest dataset in a particular library by using macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've created table from library called 'common' by using proc sql table is created with crdate by descending now I need to write macro to pick top one which is the latest dataset which is created in that library

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your library contains SAS datasets (.sas7bdat), then the following will create a macro variable `latest_dataset` with the name of the latest dataset in the COMMON library, without the use of an actual macro:

```
proc sql noprint;
select memname into: latest_dataset 
  from dictionary.tables 
  where libname='COMMON'
  having crdate=max(crdate);
%put &=latest_dataset;
```

Comment: What will this do if 2 or more datasets are tied for most recent?

Comment: It will pick one.  It will also pick one if crdate information is not available (eg if the library is a pointing at a database).  I wouldn't actually recommend this approach for selecting a particular dataset, it sounds like the process needs to be redesigned (so the required dataset can be explicity selected).